# Execute a for loop in a R script in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, r, for-loop, hana

I have written several R scripts which I call in RLANG stored procedures in SAP HANA.

So far, the scripts worked fine until I included a for-loop in the R script. I got this error.

> Could not execute 'CREATE_PROCEDURE USE_ML(IN pred "PRED", IN model "MODEL", OUT result "RES") LANGUAGE RLANG ...'
>
> SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: unterminated external language"

The piece of code I have included is similar to the following one and works fine if launched directly in my R console.

```
pred <- data.frame(vendor = as.factor(c("John", "Jack", "John", "Jack")),
                    product = as.factor(c("Milk", "Water", "Beef", "Water")))
modLevel <- list(vendor = as.factor(c("John", "William", "Jack")), 
                  product = as.factor(c("Milk","Beef", "Water", "Peanut")))
params <- c("vendor", "product")
for (p in params){ 
   pred[,p] <- factor(pred[,p], levels(modLevel[[p]]))
}
```

Needless to say that I have a larger amount of parameters I want to pass in this for-loop.

My question is the following one. Is it (1) possible to include this for-loop from R in the SQL statement without getting the syntax error or (2) must I change the structure of my script (if so, how can I) ?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT** Here is the full SQL procedure in HANA.

```
DROP PROCEDURE USE_ML_MODEL;
CREATE PROCEDURE USE_ML_MODEL(IN pred "PRED", IN model "MODEL", OUT result "RES")
LANGUAGE RLANG AS
BEGIN
    modLevel <- unserialize(model$MOD_LEV[[1]])
    params <- c("VENDOR", "PRODUCT")
    for (p in params){ 
       pred[,p] <- factor(pred[,p], levels(modLevel[[p]]))
    }
    result <- pred
END;

DROP PROCEDURE SQL_R_USE_MODEL;
CREATE PROCEDURE SQL_R_USE_MODEL(OUT result "RES")
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT AS
BEGIN
    pred = SELECT VENDOR, PRODUCT FROM "PRED";
    model = SELECT * FROM "MODEL";
    CALL USE_ML_MODEL(:pred, :model , result);
END;

CALL SQL_R_USE_MODEL("RES") WITH OVERVIEW;
```

Comment: DId you meant `modLevel[[p]]`

Comment: Yeah sure, will edit.

Comment: Please post the full `CREATE PROCEDURE...` statement so that the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Ok, just added the full SQL procedure.

Comment: How are the custom data types `pred`, `model` and `result` defined on HANA side?

Comment: All of them are defined as tables with `INTEGER` ,`VARCHAR` and `DECIMAL` for pred and result (+ `BLOB` for model).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that using a `while` loop in the R script solved the problem.

```
p <- 1
while (p < length(params)){ 
   pred[,params[p]] <- factor(pred[,params[p]], levels(modLevel[[params[p]]]))
   p <- p+1
}
```

I'll leave the question open in case someone can explain what is the problem using `for`.